# How to prove every prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ has the form:$(p,\zeta-r)=p\mathbb{Z}[\zeta] + (\zeta-r)\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

How to prove this Theorem:
 every prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ has the form:$(p,\zeta-r)=p\mathbb{Z}[\zeta] + (\zeta-r)\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ where $p$ is a prime and $r$ satisfies $f(r) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$.

Comment: What is $\zeta$?

Comment: $\zeta$ is an element added to the $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What then if $f(x)\equiv0\pmod p$ has no roots modulo $p$?

Comment: The root is r and f is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$

Comment: Let $I = (p, \zeta-r)$; then $\zeta \equiv r \bmod I$, hence every element of the ring is congruent to a rational integer modulo $I$, and this means that $I$ has degree $1$.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer can you write more about it thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. The prime ideals in $\Bbb Z[\zeta]$ above
the rational prime $p$ are $(p,g(\zeta))$ where $g$ runs through the
irreducible factors of $f(X)$ in $\Bbb Z[X]$, with possible
exceptions where $p$ divides the index of $\Bbb Z[\zeta]$ in the maximal
order (only finitely $p$ will be involved).

In general $f(X)$ will not factor completely into linear factors modulo $p$, and so
there will be prime ideals not of the form $(p,\zeta-r)$.

Comment: Oh my god this a theorem in our class....emmmmm, it is really wrong?

Comment: minimal polynomial is a irreducible

Comment: @R.Sherlock $(3)$ is a prime ideal in $\Bbb Z[i]$. Can you write it in your form?

Comment: yes it can be written as this form